# HTML - JavaScript function is not processing responseText

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a button array on my web page that is used to show the position of a robot via reading a text file with a php/ajax combo. The script sets the buttons to the same colour then changes the colour of the button to show the position of our robot. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    function position(){
    setInterval(function(){ //wait function 
    document.getElementById("A").style.background ="#008000";
    document.getElementById("B").style.background ="#008000";
    document.getElementById("C").style.background ="#008000";
    document.getElementById("D").style.background ="#008000";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){ 
            console.log(request.responseText); 
            if (request.responseText == 'A'){
                document.getElementById("A").style.background ="#ff6600";
            } else if (request.responseText == 'B'){
                document.getElementById("B").style.background ="#ff6600";
            } else if (request.responseText == 'C'){
                document.getElementById("C").style.background ="#ff6600";
            } else if (request.responseText == 'D'){
                document.getElementById("D").style.background ="#ff6600";
            } else if (request.responseText == 'E'){
                document.getElementById("E").style.background ="#ff6600";
            } else { 
                document.getElementById("A").style.background ="#ff6600";
            }
        }
    }       
    request.open('POST', 'positionupdate.php', true); //script to read text file
    request.send(); 
},3000);}       //wait
```

So, I know the php script is working because the console log shows the correct character being returned in the text file. However, my script just isn't processing the character and permanently returns the 'else' condition.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is my console log:
[image]

Comment: How do you know it is the `else` condition.?

Comment: show your `request.responseText`

Comment: Show the output of `console.log(request.responseText);`.

Comment: You should trim the response text in case you are getting extra white spaces, which could throw off your if tests

Comment: I know it's my else condition because my button 'A' is the colour to represent the position.

Comment: So in the web page window, using F12 to view to log, I receive:C

3RoboPot.php:177 1.50

RoboPot.php:209 C which is the character in the text file. (1.5 is another value being read)

Comment: Why don't you use switch instead of if else?

Comment: I'll try the switch statements approach shortly; there could be a more fundamental problem that requires addressing I feel.

Comment: Switch statements produce the same problem; the value just isn't being stored and processed. Assigned the response to a different variable, then returned that value and it still wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was I was passing an object rather than a value. In my php script, I was able to solve this by using the json_encode() function and hack together a working program.

For reference, my updated php script:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("position.txt","r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$value = fread($myfile, filesize("position.txt"));
echo json_encode($value);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```